# jar file not working java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, classpath, environment-variables, manifest, java-3d

When I run the jar file in cmd I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/j3d/Canvas3D
```

It happens both when I use `java -cp . Main` and `java -jar BallJump.jar` Im fairly sure that I set the classpath right so I have no idea why I get this error message.

This is my Manifest.txt:

```
Main-Class: Main
Class-Path: .;"C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\j3dcore.jar";"C :\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\j3dutils.jar";"C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\vecmath.jar"
```

I have tried to replace all the ";" with " " and to add " to the class path as suggested in the answers but non of them worked

Answer (score 1):

This is because the class `javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D` could not be found by the JVM, but your classes were compiled to reference it.

From a quick search, it would seem that this class is part of the `j3dcore.jar`, which you need on your classpath when running (as well as when compiling).  This is part of the Java 3D API:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html

So I would conclude that your manifest classpath is incorrectly specified in some way.  You should review the manifest doco to check if you have done something wrong:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html

**Update 2013-04-18**

> How would my manifest classpath be incorrect?

Reading the manifest tutorial I see that the classpath elements should should be *space* separated; you have semicolons.

Also, there is a limit of 72 characters on the line length; your classpath line well exceeds this.

You also have a space after the drive letter `C` in `"C :\Program Files..."`.

And note that it must be UTF-8 encoded.

You might try:

```
Main-Class: Main
Class-Path: 
 .
 "C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\j3dcore.jar"
 "C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\j3dutils.jar"
 "C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\vecmath.jar"
```

(noting the leading spaces on the classpath elements.)

Comment: How would my manifest classpath be incorrect? I have an classpath to j3dcore.jar in the manifest classpath: `C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\j3dcore.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `"` in your Class Path

```
Class Path: .;"C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\j3dcore.jar";"C
 :\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\j3dutils.jar";"C:\Program Fil
 es\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\vecmath.jar"
```

as the space makes a problem

Comment: I did that and know I get this error instead: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main$ThisPanel$1.class`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the ";" semicolon with " " space for separating your jars in `manifest.mf`

Comment: The I get this error instead:                                     `Error: Could not find or load main class Main`

Comment: have your main class in your classpath too

Comment: Isn't that what the "." in the begining is for?

Comment: `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\* Main.class
Created-By: 1.7.0_17 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: Main`